# Unable to create new native thread in Spark application

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a Spark application and I always getting an out of memory exception..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I run my program under local[5] in a node cluster on linux but it stills gives me this error..can someone point me how to rectify that in my Spark application..

Comment: have you tried to run different application and still you were getting same ?  need more details..

Comment: its hard to tell what is going wrong, what are you doing in your code?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like some problem with **`ulimit`** configured on your machine. Run the **`ulimit -a`** command, you will see below result.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63604
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63604
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

check the **`open files`** and **`max user processes`** configured values. It should be high.

You can configure them using below commands:

```
ulimit -n 10240
ulimit -u 63604
```

Once you are done with configuration of ulimits. You can start your application to see the effect.